# weblogic reading .ser file on startup

Tags: weblogic

I have a .ser file which supposed to be intialized within weblogic server on server start.

I have created my own domain in weblogic 12c in windows os.

Which place would be ideally to store that .ser file to get initialize on server start up ?

Do i need to write any script here ?

Please let me know.

Comment: What? Can you add more details? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: @castling .ser contains serialized metadata.  I am migrating from oc4j to weblogic server. In oc4j server, .ser file is stored in "oracle/OracleAS_1/j2ee/home".  Similarly i am looking for right location in weblogic to store that file.  If i dont do this, i get error as "cannot initialize metadata". My application which is deployed on this weblogic throws that error.

Comment: Can't you just add the path to the .ser file to your classpath? You can do that in setDomainEnv.sh, startWebLogic.sh, or by editing the `Server Start` tab inside the admin console

Comment: @castling. I have placed .ser file in domain folder and declared its path in setDomainENV.sh and startWeblogic.sh and tried to execute call command as ' call "%{DOMAIN_HOME}%/ClassNameHash.ser" ' . I dont see any change. Am i did wrong here ? After placing .ser file in a location, how to declare that path in .sh files? –

Comment: I'm still a bit confused what you're doing but my guess would be to edit startWebLogic.sh and put in a line like `CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}:/path/to/folder/containing/ser/file` so the .ser file is in your classpath. executing `call "%{DOMAIN_HOME}%/ClassNameHash.ser` won't do anything

Comment: @castling I tried adding path as said above like this.  1.  set POST_CLASSPATH=%POST_CLASSPATH%;%DATABASE_CLASSPATH%
  ;C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain
  ;/path/to/folder/containing/ser/file   2. Placed .ser file in base_domain/ folder.  Still having same issue.  Actually .ser file should get initialize and load when i start the server. Is there any reference link where i can refer how to convey weblogic to read .ser file from domain folder?